# Error in proof of $Y=F(X)$ uniform on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, self-study, uniform-distribution

If we let $Y=F_X(X)$ then $Y\sim U(0,1)$, which is proved in introductory texts in statistics (for example Casella and Berger *Statisical Inference* p. 54).

What is then the **error** in the "proof" below? (Where I try to prove that $F_Y(y)=y$.)

$$F_Y(y)=
\text{P}(Y\leq y)\stackrel{(\star)}{=}\text{P}(F_X(X)\leq F_X(x))=\text{P}(F_X^{-1}(F_X(X))\leq F_X^{-1}(F_X(x)))=\text{P}(X\leq x)=F_X(x),
$$
where we in transition $(\star)$ have used that $Y=F_X(X), y=F_X(x)$,

Comment: Your third step doesn't make a lot of sense since you're introducing $x$ which doesn't appear on the left hand side.

Comment: @dsaxton, is not $y=F_X(x)$? You are saying that the error is in transition $(\star)$?

Comment: $y$ is just the argument of the function and there's no reason to give it another name midway through a calculation.  If $F_X(x)$ is just defined to equal $y$, haven't you concluded $F_Y(y) = y$ as desired?

Comment: What is this supposed to be a proof of?

Comment: @Student001, I try to prove that $F_Y(y)=y$, so that $Y\sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @dsaxton. I am still a little bit confused. If $Y=F_X(X)$ should not $y=F_X(x)$ as well? Since if you have a relisation $x$ from $X$, then the realisation of $Y=F_X(X)$ is $y=F_X(x)$? Am I mixing some concepts here?

Comment: $y$ is just a, fixed, real number in your first quantity. Call it something else if that helps to not confuse it with a random variable or the realization thereof, say $s$. Then $P(Y\leq s) = P(F_X(X) \leq s) = P(X \leq F^{-1}_X(s)) = F_X(F_X^{-1}(s))...$

Comment: B.t.w, for a real proof you may have to motivate some of the equalities in the case where $F_X$ does not have an inverse $F_X^{-1}$ in the usual sense, but that's another matter.

Comment: Do not substitute $F_X(x)$ for $y$, just use $y$.  I think you've confused yourself by doing this.  Also the statement $P(F^{-1}(F_X(X)))$ is not clear because the thing inside $P$ is not an event.  Start with $P(F_X(X) \leq y)$ and go from here, it's only a couple more steps and you basically already have them above.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @Student I believe that finding a useful definition of $F_X^{-1}$ that preserves the probability inequality (at the third step) is the *entirety* of the matter.  Everything else looks fine, because it's purely a matter of notation and the definitions.

Comment: FredrikAa: Strangely, your "proof," when applied to a Bernoulli$(p)$ variable (for which $F_X$ attains only three distinct values $0,p,1$) appears to show that $Y=F_X(X)$, which *a fortiori* can have only those three values, has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @whuber Sure, if finding a definition also includes understanding it. As a student it's also not uncommon to be given a definition and then being asked to motivate it's use, or it's inapplicability.

Comment: @Student: by "finding" I meant *discovering it on one's own,* not asking someone else to supply it.